# Does I3C addressing assign stable addresses based on physical displacement?

Tags: addressing, i3c

I'm potentially looking at making a modular keyboard, where I have a single unit for each key (a la [these atoms](https://hackaday.io/project/190256-polykybd-displays-in-your-keycaps/log/217046-the-first-working-pcb-design) someone else used for experimenting), and I became curious about what would happen with I3C dynamic addressing.

For identical I3C devices placed on a bus (and without daisy-chaining them), would the host/controller be able to detect (in effect) *how far away* each device is, and assign an address based on that?  Consider the following diagram, based on an abbreviated view of the left half of the keyboard home row:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPi5wz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there any way for me to differentiate between the atom that should be assigned to "Key A" from "Key G" (and all of them in between) *without* manually programming each key individually?  That is, I want the module positioned at "Key A" to be assigned "Address 1" and the one for "Key G" to be assigned "Address 5", even if/when I swap the individual key atoms.

---

Obviously, this isn't necessarily the only or best way to do this;

- I could use multiple wires and directly connect to parts on the atom, as is done in the original (forgoing any I3C client microcontroller).  This increases the number of pins required, though.
- I could (and maybe should) assign static I2C addresses, but this wouldn't allow me to determine which atom should be assigned to "Key A".  I'd need some other signal mechanism...
- I could have the equivalent of chip-select lines, but this wouldn't be a benefit over SPI...

Comment: Doesn't look like there's an I3C tag yet, and I don't have the reputation to create it.  Any other relevant tags here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3C_(bus) *You never stop learning*

Comment: What do you mean when you say "atoms"?

Comment: that behavior is already implemented in addressable LED strips

Comment: @jsotola - All the addressable LED strips I'm aware of use (single signal wire) daisy-chained SPI.  They're not on a common bus wire.  If I tried to do the equivalent for this setup, messages to any individual key has to transit through all the others, including the return for data out.  I want to avoid that.

Comment: @Andyaka - Essentially, a small self-contained PCB with a simple microcontroller, that talks to the main host microcontroller over some protocol.  Each atom would have sensors and other devices on them, roughly equivalent to the PCBs in the included link, but that part isn't really relevant.  The real question is, "given identical target boards, can I detect what physical displacement order they're connected in".

Comment: @MiNiMe - That link is a general description of I3C, but it doesn't tell me how addresses are assigned with multiple devices on the same bus.  Most descriptions I've seen of the situation seem to assume that the actual physical location of the client device isn't relative - either because each device is completely unique, or because they're used in aggregate (or that post-address config is available, which may not be the case here).  Unless you had something else in mind for the link?

Comment: you could use a LED strip like circuit only for assigning addresses ... the data bus would still be common bus

Comment: @jsotola - Sure, that's an option.  But that means I need to add at least another wire (and possibly another chip), which I'm curious to know if I can avoid.